# Nodejs Sequelize Associations/Relations include

Tags: node.js, include, associations, sequelize.js, findall

I'm trying to understand why this problem is happening.
For example:

```
var channel = sequelize.define('channel', {...})
var video = sequelize.define('video',{...})

channel.hasMany(video)
```

So far so good, but when I try this:

```
video.findAll({ include: [model:channel] }).then( function(video) {
   // return video with channel, not just the number id
}
```

I got error:

Unhandled rejection Error: channel is not associated to video!

What am I doing wrong??

ps: if I try the findAll method for channels, including the video model, it works, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need specify the belongs to dependency from channel in video to work with "include" on the video model queries.

```
video.belongsTo(channel);
```

before to perform findAll query should solve the problem.

```
video.findAll({ include: channel }).then( function(videos) {
   // return video with channel, not just the number id
}
```